# Cannot Start MySQL Server on Fresh MAMP Install

Tags: macos, mysql, mamp

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.2 on my Macbook Pro.

I can get the apache server to start, but not the mysql server, on both the default apache and default MAMP ports. When I try to go to my start page, I get the message "Error: Could not connect to MySQL server!" . Here's what's in my mysql error log:

```
00513 02:00:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
100513 02:00:16 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
100513 2:00:16 [Warning] The syntax '--log_slow_queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow_query_log'/'--slow_query_log_file' instead.
100513 2:00:16 [Warning] You have forced lower_case_table_names to 0 through a command-line option, even though your file system '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/' is case insensitive. This means that you can corrupt a MyISAM table by accessing it with different cases. You should consider changing lower_case_table_names to 1 or 2
100513 2:00:16 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
100513 2:00:16 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
100513 2:00:16 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
InnoDB: Error: log file /usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 16777216 bytes!
100513 2:00:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
100513 2:00:16 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
100513 2:00:16 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'
100513 2:00:16 [ERROR] Aborting
100513 2:00:16 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
100513 02:00:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

A couple of things:

1) There are a bunch of different .cnf files that come with MAMP (my-huge, my-medium, etc.)...how can I tell which one is actually being used?
2) I deleted the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 as recommended by another post on serverfault, and then ended up with more errors:

```
100519 16:01:30  InnoDB: Log file /usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file /usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile0 size to 16 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
100519 16:01:30  InnoDB: Log file /usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file /usr/local/mysql/data/ib_logfile1 size to 16 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
100519 16:01:31  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
100519 16:01:31  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44556
100519 16:01:31 [ERROR] /Applications/MAMP/Library/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'
100519 16:01:31 [ERROR] Aborting
```

And then I got this the next time I tried to run it:

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock /usr/local/mysql/data/ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process 
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

Sorry that this is a lot of information, but I don't want to leave anything out. Thanks.

Comment: mysqld is the script that starts up the server, right? '--skip -bdb' is not in my my.cnf file, so I think MAMP thinks there's another my.cnf file somewhere else, but it doesn't show up in my search.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, and i noticed that after a restart of the computer, mysql doesn't start up, when I'd quit MAMP and then tried to start it again, only Apache starts...

**The 'fix' that worked for me is to quit MAMP**, use the activity monitor to quit all instances of 'mysqld' and then restart MAMP.

Answer (score 1):

This definately sounds like you have alot of MySQL processes running and you just need to quit all mysql processes and then start up MySQL.  Open your terminal and issue:

```
kill -s 15 `http://softwaregravy.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/ls-colors-for-mac/`
```

Confirm with:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql | grep -v grep
```

If there are still processes that come up, you will need to force kill all the processes:

```
kill -s 9 `http://softwaregravy.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/ls-colors-for-mac/`
```

Confirm and then start MySQL via MAMP's Control panel as you normally would.